# How to understand "document" of page evaluation code in phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs

**How to understand "document" in below code?**

```
*var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function(status) {
  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.title;
  });*
```

The function in evaluation part does not define what is the document so I feel very confused where this document comes from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you write this code? I presume not. Usually document is a global variable which in the browser refers to the current web page, and document.title will be the title of the page

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense to me. I am learning PhantomJS and this code belongs to someone else:)@Mikkel